# How to create an Observable sequence of bytes from an input stream in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I am new to RxJava, hence, asking this question. I have an input stream which I have to convert to a sequence of byte arrays of specific size. Something like:

```
Observable
  .just(inputStream)
  .map(new Func1<InputStream, Chunk>());
```

Here `Chunk` is a custom class which contains the number of bytes read from the stream. Could someone help me understand how to do this in RxJava

Answer (score 4):

Use `StringObservable.from(InputStream, chunkSize)` from [RxJavaString](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaString). It will return an `Observable<byte[]>` and supports backpressure (won't read from the `InputStream` unless requested by downstream).

By the way [`Observable.using`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#using(rx.functions.Func0,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Action1)) completes the picture for closing resources properly. You can use `Bytes.from(file, chunkSize)` from [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras) if you are reading bytes from a file (it uses `Observable.using` under the covers).

Comment: Thanks Dave for providing me some guideline. `StringObservable` will not work for me because the files can be binary (images, videos etc.) and yes, the file sizes could be in GBs. I have a quick question though; does `Bytes.from` consider backpressure?

Comment: It's called `StringObservable` but it's badly named for this method. It deals with bytes only as I indicated. `Bytes.from` uses the same technique as `StringObservable` (predates its existence) and yes supports backpressure.

Comment: Hi, RxJavaString is taken from 1.x branch. Any plans for moving implementation to 2.x branch?

Comment: For RxJava 2.x you can use rxjava2-extras or RxJava2Extensions

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observable.create followed by flatMap. Note that by default QueuedProducer is unbounded, you can supply a custom implementation including a bounding queue.

for example:

```
  static class Chunk {
    byte[] buf;
    int size;
    int index;
    public Chunk(byte[] buf, int size, int index) {
      this.buf = buf;
      this.size = size;
      this.index = index;
    }

  }

  FileInputStream fis = ...
  Observable<Chunk> o = Observable.just(fis).flatMap(new Func1<InputStream, Observable<Chunk>>() {

  @Override
  public Observable<Chunk> call(InputStream is) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Chunk>() {

      public void call(Subscriber<? super Chunk> subscriber) {
        final QueuedProducer<Chunk> producer = new QueuedProducer<>(subscriber);
        subscriber.setProducer(producer);
        try {
          int size = 0;
          int index = 0;
          do {
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            size = is.read(buf);
            if (size > 0) {
              Chunk chunk = new Chunk(buf, size, index++);
              System.out.println("Producing chunk #" + index + " of size: " + chunk.size);
              producer.onNext(chunk);
            }
          } while (size >= 0);
          producer.onCompleted();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          producer.onError(e);
        } finally {
          try {
            System.out.println("Closing stream");
            is.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
 }
});

o.subscribe(new Action1<Chunk>() {

  @Override
  public void call(Chunk chunk) {
    System.out.println("Received chunk #" + chunk.index + " of size: " + chunk.size);

  }

});

Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: So this may work but has an important drawback. If the stream is large, the consumer is slow and an asynchronous boundary is crossed downstream then you can run out of memory. It's better to use a full backpressure supporting solution like extending `SyncOnSubscribe` which is what my solution does.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that bounded queue can be supplied (such as BlockingLinkedQueue) though I agree full backpressure support would be much nicer for really large sources.